# Apache mod_rewrite to domain/IP

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, dns, debian

I want to do a simple passthru with Apache. When I open http://www.abc.com/45.34.81.171, Apache should internally proxify the URL http://45.34.81.171/ by the using following rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://$1:80/ [P]
```

but it doesn't. Instead I get a "400 Bad Request". Modules are enabled and Apache was restarted after editing the htaccess. It works, when I enter a static IP as the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://85.17.26.104:80/ [P]
```

Any ideas?

Thank you for any reply!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it without specifying port 80 (as it's 80 by default)? Also it might add extra slash to the end, giving something like http://45.34.81.171/:80/ (so without a port it should work if that was the case)

Comment: Thank you! The Problem was not the slash at the and, but it added a trailing slash at the front, so that an invalid link, like http:///45.34.81.171:80/ was generated. Now it works by unsing the following rule: `RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ http://$1:80 [P]`